# A geometric proof that there are infinitely many primes?

Tags: nt.number-theory, mg.metric-geometry, prime-numbers, inequalities

Let $e_d$ be the $d$-th standard-basis vector in the Hilbert space $H=l_2(\mathbb{N})$.
Let $h(n)  = J_2(n)$ be the second Jordan totient function, defined by:

$$J_2(n) = n^2 \prod_{p|n}(1-1/p^2)$$
Define:

$$\phi(n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n}\sqrt{h(d)} e_d.$$

Then we have:

$$ \left < \phi(a),\phi(b) \right > = \frac{\gcd(a,b)^2}{ab}=:k(a,b)$$

The vectors $\phi(a_i)$ are linearly independent for each finite set $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ of natural numbers, [since (page 1,2 in the notes)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vPz4llzvv9dup3RcJxvCCgrE-RLXwu4h/view)

$$\det(G_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{h(a_i)}{a_i^2} $$
is not zero, where $G_n$ denotes the Gram matrix.

We want to look at $a_1,\cdots,a_n = 1,\cdots,n$ and get:

$$d(n):=\det(G_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{h(i)}{i^2}  = \prod_{k=1}^n \prod_{p|k} (1-1/p^2) = \prod_{p \le n} (1-1/p^2)^{\operatorname{floor}(n/p)}$$

Supposing now, that there exist only finitely many primes $p_1,\cdots,p_r$ we get for $d(n)$:

$$d(n) = \prod_{i=1}^r (1-1/p_i^2)^{\operatorname{floor}(n/p_i)}$$

Consider now the number $N = p_1 \cdots p_r$ then we have:

$$\operatorname{floor}(N/p_i) = \operatorname{floor}((N+1)/p_i)$$

hence also:

$$d(N) = d(N+1)$$

But this [should be empirically impossible](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwtjkEKhTAMRPeCd8gy0aqty483EQWhrQj-tES9v62aWc6bzFjnwVpk-pUFpBN3XsIQJVgc0TSmi3NPVeX3EAS5iwQ-CETYMrT93YFcG5qoLF5ll7MrC68Ojeq1TsD3PkX4RFZPZa1brZ72BAzvDLoBhYQm7g==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), if the function $d(n)$ can be shown to be monotonically decreasing. Notice also that the volume $\operatorname{vol}(n) = \sqrt{d(n)}$ is the volume spaned by the vectors $\phi(k), k=1,\cdots,n$. Hence maybe a geometric inequality could be applied in this setting?

**Question:
Is it possible to show that $d$ is monotonically decreasing in $n$ and thereby giving a geometric proof of the infinitude of primes?**

**Edit**: With the help of @Mark the proof is now complete! I still do not understand the downvote yet. :-(

Comment: related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373475/a-geometric-approach-to-the-odd-perfect-number-problem

Comment: Isn't $d(n+1)/d(n) = \prod_{p\mid n+1} (1-p^{-2}) < 1$?

Comment: @Mark: I am not sure how you mean this comment?

Comment: Each $\prod_{p\mid n+1}(1-p^{-2})$ is the product of many terms in $(0,1)$, and is therefore in $(0,1)$ itself (and notably $<1$). It appears that $d(n+1)/d(n)$ is precisely this quantity, so therefore $d(n+1)<d(n)$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: @Mark: I am not sure how you arrive at this expression, therefore I programmed it to see if $d(n+1)/d(n)$ is equal to your expression, and it seems that it is not: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=rosgpt

Comment: Your display states "we want to look at ... $d(n):=\det(G_n) = \prod_{i = 1}^n\frac{h(i)}{i^2} = \prod_{k = 1}^n\prod_{p\mid k}1-p^{-2}$. This seemed to be where $d(n)$ was defined, and by this definition the result seemed obvious.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks for your comment. However I get that: $d(n)=\prod_{k=1}^n \prod_{p|k} (1-1/p^2) = \prod_{p \le n} (1-1/p^2)^{\operatorname{floor}(n/p)}$ which I can verify empirically: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=yuaowe (d1=dd) and it should follow theoretically. If it is not asked too much: It would be nice to promote your comment into an answer, so that I can follow your reasoning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have claimed twice that

$$
d(n)= \prod_{k = 1}^n \prod_{p\mid k}(1-p^{-2})
$$

If this is true, your desired claim immediately holds, namely $d(n+1) <d(n)$.
This is because the quotient

$$
\frac{d(n+1)}{d(n)} = \frac{\prod_{k = 1}^{n+1}\prod_{p\mid k}(1-p^{-2})}{\prod_{k = 1}^n\prod_{p\mid k}(1-p^{-2})} = \prod_{p\mid (n+1)}(1-p^{-2}).
$$
Note that for any non-trivial divisor $p\mid (n+1)$, we have that $p>1$, and therefore $0 < p^{-2} < 1$, and $0<1-p^{-2} < 1$.
It therefore follows that the product of these numbers in $(0,1)$ is in $(0,1)$, i.e.

$$\frac{d(n+1)}{d(n)} < 1\implies d(n+1) < d(n),$$

as desired.

Comment: Sorry , you are correct and so am I. I just misread $p|(n+1)$ to $p\le n+1$. This was the point of irritation. I have accepted your answer. Thanks for this. This completes the proof.