# On the nearest-square function and the quantity $m^2 - p^k$ where $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number

Tags: nt.number-theory, inequalities, conjectures, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

This question has been cross-posted from this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3902896) and is an offshoot of this [other MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3555053).

(Note that [MSE user mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/78967) has posted an [answer in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3903162/28816), which I could not completely understand.  I have therefore cross-posted this question in MO, hoping the sages here would be able to give some enlightenment.  I hope this is okay, and that the question is research-level.)

Let $n = p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

It was conjectured in [Dris (2008)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1450) and [Dris (2012)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html) that the inequality $p^k < m$ holds.

[Brown (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591) showed that the Dris Conjecture (that $p^k < m$) holds in many cases.

It is trivial to show that $m^2 - p^k \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.  This means that $m^2 - p^k = 4z$, where it is known that $4z \geq {10}^{375}$.  (See this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3556316) and [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3557070/28816), where the case $m < p^k$ is considered.)  Note that if $p^k < m$, then $$m^2 - p^k > m^2 - m = m(m - 1),$$
and that
$${10}^{1500} < n = p^k m^2 < m^3$$
where the lower bound for the magnitude of the odd perfect number $n$ is due to [Ochem and Rao (2012)](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2012-81-279/S0025-5718-2012-02563-4/S0025-5718-2012-02563-4.pdf).  This results in a larger lower bound for $m^2 - p^k$.  Therefore, unconditionally, we have
$$m^2 - p^k \geq {10}^{375}.$$
We now endeavor to **disprove** the Dris Conjecture.

Consider the following sample proof arguments:

**Theorem 1** If $n = p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number satisfying $m^2 - p^k = 8$, then $m < p^k$.

**Proof**

Let $p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number satisfying $m^2 - p^k = 8$.

Then $$(m + 3)(m - 3) = m^2 - 9 = p^k - 1.$$

This implies that $(m + 3) \mid (p^k - 1)$, from which it follows that
$$m < m + 3 \leq p^k - 1 < p^k.$$
We therefore conclude that $m < p^k$.

**QED**

**Theorem 2** If $n = p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number satisfying $m^2 - p^k = 40$, then $m < p^k$.

**Proof**

Let $p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number satisfying $m^2 - p^k = 40$.

Then $$(m+7)(m-7)=m^2 - 49=p^k - 9,$$
from which it follows that
$$(m+7) \mid (p^k - 9)$$
which implies that
$$m < m+7 \leq p^k - 9 < p^k.$$

**QED**

Note that $49$ is not the **nearest square** to $40$ ($36$ is), but rather the nearest square **larger** than $40$.

With this minor adjustment in the logic, I would expect the general proof argument to work.

(Additionally, note that it is known that $m^2 - p^k$ is **not a square**, if $p^k m^2$ is an OPN with special prime $p$.  See this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3121498) and the [answer contained therein](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3122247/28816).)

So now consider the equation $m^2 - p^k = 4z$.  Following our proof strategy, we have:

Subtracting the smallest square that is larger than $m^2 - p^k$, we obtain

$$m^2 - \bigg(\lceil{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k}}\rceil\bigg)^2 = p^k + \Bigg(4z - \bigg(\lceil{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k}}\rceil\bigg)^2\Bigg).$$

> So the only remaining question now is whether it could be proved that
> $$\Bigg(4z - \bigg(\lceil{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k}}\rceil\bigg)^2\Bigg) = -y < 0$$
> for some **positive** integer $y$?

In other words, is it possible to prove that it is always the case that
$$\Bigg((m^2 - p^k) - \bigg(\lceil{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k}}\rceil\bigg)^2\Bigg) < 0,$$
if $n = p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$?

If so, it would follow that
$$\Bigg(m + \lceil{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k}}\rceil\Bigg)\Bigg(m - \lceil{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k} }\rceil\Bigg) = p^k - y$$
which would imply that
$$\Bigg(m + \lceil{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k}}\rceil\Bigg) \mid (p^k - y)$$
from which it follows that
$$m < \Bigg(m + \lceil{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k}}\rceil\Bigg) \leq p^k - y < p^k.$$

Comment: "We now endeavor to disprove the Dris Conjecture"

I'm not sure what you mean  by this. Wouldn't a disproof by nature need to mean one had an actual odd perfect number as a counterexample?

Comment: If indeed $m-a=\sqrt{m^2 - p^k}$, then $m^2 - 2am + a^2 = m^2 - p^k$. This implies that $p^k = 2am - a^2 = a(2m - a)$, from which it follows that $0 < a < 1$. We conclude that $p^k < 2m$.

Comment: In particular, this means that, under the problematic case, $m^2 - p^k > m^2 - 2m$, so that the smallest square larger than $m^2 - p^k$ is $m^2 - 2m + 1 = (m - 1)^2$.  Does this proof suffice, @mathlove?

Comment: I don't know why you can say that the smallest square larger than $m^2-p^k$ is $(m-1)^2$. It is possible that $m^2-2m\lt (m-1)^2\lt m^2-p^k$.

Comment: Since $m^2 - p^k$ is not a square, then $m^2 - p^k \neq (m-1)^2$. Note that $m^2 - p^k < (m-1)^2 = m^2 - 2m + 1$ is impossible since $m^2 - 2m < m^2 - p^k$. Therefore, the smallest square that is larger than $m^2 - p^k$ is $m^2$. OHH NO, @mathlove! =(

Comment: If you could summarize the findings so far in an answer, I would greatly appreciate it @mathlove.

Comment: I've summarized the findings so far in an answer. Also, I deleted my comments saying that yours is not a research question since your main interest is now "is it true that $m\not=\left\lceil\sqrt{m^2-p^k}\right\rceil$ ?" which might be a research level question.

Comment: I have some closely related number-theoretic investigations going on over at [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445636).  Would you mind taking a look, @mathlove?  Thank you in advance for your time and attention!  =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Middle of page 6 of
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6001v10.pdf

" we always have $0 < n−\lceil\sqrt{n^2−q^k}\rceil$ "

No, this requires that $q^k\ge 2n-1$,
an helpful assumption when the goal is to prove $q^k > n$.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking if $m\lt p^k$ can be proved in the following way :

We have
$$\Bigg(m + \left\lceil{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k}}\right\rceil\Bigg)\Bigg(m - \left\lceil{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k} }\right\rceil\Bigg) = p^k +4z - \left\lceil{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k}}\right\rceil^2$$
which implies
$$\bigg(m + \left\lceil{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k}}\right\rceil\bigg) \mid \bigg(p^k +4z - \left\lceil{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k}}\right\rceil^2\bigg)$$
from which it follows that
$$m < m + \left\lceil{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k}}\right\rceil \leq p^k +4z - \left\lceil{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k}}\right\rceil^2 < p^k.\quad\square$$

This is not correct since this does not work when $m =\left\lceil{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k} }\right\rceil$.

(If it is true that $m \not=\left\lceil{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k} }\right\rceil$, then your method works.)

---

In the comments, you are trying to prove $m \not=\left\lceil{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k} }\right\rceil$ in the following way :

Suppose that $m=\left\lceil{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k} }\right\rceil$. Then, there is an $a\in[0,1)$ such that $m-a=\sqrt{m^2-p^k}$. Squaring the both sides, we get $p^k=2am-a^2$ which implies $p^k\lt 2m$ to have $m^2-p^k\gt (m-1)^2-1$. So, we see that the smallest square larger than $m^2-p^k$ is $(m-1)^2$, which is a contradiction.$\quad\square$

This is not correct since it is possible that $(m-1)^2-1\lt (m-1)^2\lt m^2-p^k$.

Comment: Eureka, @mathlove!  [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174145](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174145)