# On odd perfect numbers $p^k m^2$ with special prime $p$ satisfying $m^2 - p^k = 2^r t$ - Part II

Tags: nt.number-theory, open-problems, divisors-multiples, conjectures, perfect-numbers

(**Preamble:** We have asked this same question in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4269988) two weeks ago, without getting any answers.  We have therefore cross-posted it to MO, hoping that it gets answered here.)

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.

If $n$ is odd and $\sigma(n)=2n$, then we call $n$ an *odd perfect number*.  Euler proved that a hypothetical odd perfect number must necessarily have the form $n = p^k m^2$ where $p$ is the *special prime* satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Descartes, Frenicle, and subsequently [Sorli](http://hdl.handle.net/10453/20034) conjectured that $k=1$ always holds.  Dris conjectured that the inequality $p^k < m$ is true in his [M. Sc.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1450) [thesis](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html).

[Brown (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591) eventually produced a proof for the weaker inequality $p < m$. (Pomerance informed Brown that our past proofs for the estimate $p < m$ may be (inherently) flawed. See this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443950) for the details of Pomerance's rebuttal.)

Now, [recent](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376268) [evidence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393738) suggests that $p^k < m$ may in fact be false.

**THE ARGUMENT**

Let $n = p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $p$.

Since $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $m$ is odd, then $m^2 - p^k \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.  Moreover, $m^2 - p^k$ is **not a square** ([Dris and San Diego (2020)](http://nntdm.net/volume-26-2020/number-4/33-38/)). Note: I am already too sleepy to add the details, but Dris and San Diego's proof in NNTDM for the statement "$m^2 - p^k$ is **not a square**" is incomplete and flawed as originally published since our proof makes use of the estimate $p < m$. (Nonetheless, it is still *possible* to prove the same statement, essentially by using Acquaah and Konyagin's result in [(IJNT, 2012)](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/s1793042112500935). Will submit a corrigendum for [(Dris and San Diego (2020))](http://nntdm.net/volume-26-2020/number-4/33-38/) to NNTDM as soon as possible.)

This implies that we may write
$$m^2 - p^k = 2^r t$$
where $r \geq 2$ and $2^r \neq t$.  (I have removed the condition $\gcd(2,t)=1$ since we still have not completely ruled out the possibility that $m^2 - p^k$ may be a power of two.  We do know that under the assumption that $k=1$ holds, then $m^2 - p^k$ is not a power of two when $p$ is a Fermat prime.)

It is trivial to prove that $m \neq 2^r$ and $m \neq t$, so that we consider the following cases:

$$\text{Case (1):  } m > t > 2^r$$
$$\text{Case (2):  } m > 2^r > t$$
$$\text{Case (3):  } t > m > 2^r$$
$$\text{Case (4):  } 2^r > m > t$$
$$\text{Case (5):  } t > 2^r > m$$
$$\text{Case (6):  } 2^r > t > m$$

Note that these six (6) cases may be summarized as:

$$\text{Case (A):  } m > \max(2^r, t)$$
Cases (1) and (2) are included under this Case (A).

$$\text{Case (B):  } \max(2^r, t) > m > \min(2^r, t)$$
Cases (3) and (4) are included under this Case (B).

$$\text{Case (C):  } \min(2^r, t) > m$$
Cases (5) and (6) are included under this Case (C).

---

We can easily rule out Case **(5)** and Case **(6)**, as follows:

Under Case **(5)**, we have $m < t$ and $m < 2^r$, which implies that $m^2 < 2^r t$.  This gives
$$5 \leq p^k = m^2 - 2^r t < 0,$$
which is a contradiction.

Under Case **(6)**, we have $m < 2^r$ and $m < t$, which implies that $m^2 < 2^r t$.  This gives
$$5 \leq p^k = m^2 - 2^r t < 0,$$
which is a contradiction.

---

Under Case **(1)** and Case **(2)**, we can prove that the inequality $m < p^k$ holds, as follows:

Under Case **(1)**, we have:
$$(m - t)(m + 2^r) > 0$$
$$p^k = m^2 - 2^r t > m(t - 2^r) = m\left|2^r - t\right|.$$

Under Case **(2)**, we have:
$$(m - 2^r)(m + t) > 0$$
$$p^k = m^2 - 2^r t > m(2^r - t) = m\left|2^r - t\right|.$$

---

So we are now left with Case **(3)** and Case **(4)**.

Under Case **(3)**, we have:
$$(m + 2^r)(m - t) < 0$$
$$p^k = m^2 - 2^r t < m(t - 2^r) = m\left|2^r - t\right|.$$

Under Case **(4)**, we have:
$$(m - 2^r)(m + t) < 0$$
$$p^k = m^2 - 2^r t < m(2^r - t) = m\left|2^r - t\right|.$$

Note that, under Case **(3)** and Case **(4)**, we actually have
$$\min(2^r,t) < m < \max(2^r,t).$$

But the condition $\left|2^r - t\right|=1$ is sufficient for $p^k < m$ to hold.

Our inquiry is:

> **QUESTION:** Is the condition $\left|2^r - t\right|=1$ also necessary for $p^k < m$ to hold, under Case **(3)** and Case **(4)**?

Note that the condition $\left|2^r - t\right|=1$ contradicts the inequality
$$\min(2^r,t) < m < \max(2^r,t),$$
under the remaining Case **(3)** and Case **(4)**, and the fact that $m$ is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **QUESTION:** Is the condition $\left|2^r - t\right|=1$ also necessary for $p^k < m$ to hold, under Case **(3)** and Case **(4)**?

The answer is no.

It is true that $p^k\lt m\implies |2^r-t|\not=1$.

*Proof* :

Since you ruled out (5) and (6), and showed that, under (1) or (2), $m < p^k$ holds, one can say that it is true that $p^k\lt m\implies$ (3) or (4).

Also, since, under (3) or (4), $2^r$ and $t$ cannot be consecutive integers, one can say that $|2^r-t|\not=1$.

As a result, one can say that
$$p^k\lt m\implies (3)\ \text{or}\ (4)\implies |2^r-t|\not=1.\quad\blacksquare$$

Answer (score 2):

You wrote

> $$\implies (a + 1)p^k + b(a + 1) = p^k + b + ap^k + ab = p^k + c$$Comparing coefficients, we obtain$$a + 1 = 1 \text{ and } b(a + 1) = c$$

I don't think that this is correct since it is not true that

$$(a + 1)p^k + b(a + 1)  = p^k + c\implies a+1=1$$

For example, if
$$a=2,\quad b=2,\quad c=16,\quad p=5,\quad k=1$$
then
$$(a + 1)p^k + b(a + 1) = p^k + c$$
holds.

Comment: Do you think that this rules out **any** proof for the implication
$$p^k < m \implies \left|2^r - t\right| = 1,$$
@mathlove?

Comment: @Jose Arnaldo Bebita Dris : No, I don't. Someone might be able to prove in another way that $p^k\lt m\implies |2^r-t|=1$.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your feedback, @mathlove!  =)

Comment: We have decided to award the 100 bounty to your answer, @mathlove, as it helped to clarify some things for us.